# How can i use env file in node

Tags: node.js

How can I use env file in node. When I create env file and put my mongo db user and password using
DB_USER and DB_PASS it will not working now what can I do.
DB_USER=deep
DB_PASS=rkYcBBmeI1fAX03K

Comment: Where do you use that env file? Are you using `dotenv` or similar to load it? `source`ing it manually? Give a [mre].

Comment: just a comment to say: I hope it is not your production or staging mongo password! Do not share sensitive data on Stackoverflow. Otherwise, https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv works like a charm for env variables

Comment: What is the exact problem? how and where you are using the variables? which package you are using?

Comment: @François its just a demo password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) for pass env with command Or create .env file:

In this case, the parameters is available to you automatically

and can get env parameters as follows

process.env.DB_PASS

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use [confme](https://github.com/koorchik/node-confme). Its a great solution to stay compatible with standard dotenv but with additional validation and default layer. Also good solution for zero-configuration.

Validation schema must be implemented according to [LIVR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livr) rules. Good decision to be sure of the integrity and correct values in your config.